# Facebook review and detection if app is installed?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am using facebook ShareOpenGraphObject to share a custom object, I am sharing this story with an image and this only makes it feasible to work with a facebook app installed on the device.

Now I have two questions:
I want to submit my app for review for the custom share object I have created for this app, as it stands I do not require a facebook login as it is mapped with the Facebook app. However on the review tab in console I see this:

Facebook Login Integration (required)

So should the above only just be a placeholder with no real function?

Second if I want to fall back to the webshare dialog, ***how do I detect if the Facebook app is installed on the Android device?*** so that I remove the photo part and instead allow the user to post a link?

Comment: Where would you share to if there isn't a Facebook Login? Are you using the ShareDialog?

Comment: A login button is not required if you are using ShareOpenGraphObject. It checks for your ap login on the device.